# C - some methods are not being called from a menu method

Tags: c

I'm writing a blackjack program for uni and some methods are simply not being called. 
this menu method is part of the assign1.c file which contains the main method. the other methods are in other .c files but I have checked the #include parts of my code many times and they are all 100% correct.
The menu prints fine and i is set to the input correctly, but when the appropriate if statement is called the method within them is not. here is the code

edit: specifically the playGame() method i understand the other ones arent being called properly but the playgame one is giving me the most grief.

```
int mainmenu(){
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while (j<1) {
    printf("\n");
    printf("Black Jack - Main Menu\n");
    printf("1) Play Game\n");
    printf("2) Display Scores\n");
    printf("3) Reset Scores\n");
    printf("4) Quit\n");
    printf("\n" "Make your selection: ");

scanf("%d", &i);
if (i==1) {
    Player* playGame(Player *computer, Player *human, Card *deck);
    int testmethod();
}
else if (i==2) {
    printScoreBoard();
}
else if (i==3) {
    resetScores();
}
else if (i==4){
    j++;
}
else{
    printf("%s\n",  "Incorrect input, please try again");

    int ch;
    /* remove all characters from the buffer */
    while(ch = getc(stdin), ch!='\n' && ch!=EOF)
        ;
    /* clear the error status of the input pointer */
    clearerr(stdin);

}


}

return 0;
```

}

if I debug it simply ignores the methods as if they are not executable code or something.
any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually *calling* the functions, you are just *declaring* them e.g.:

```
if (i==1) {
    Player* playGame(Player *computer, Player *human, Card *deck);
    int testmethod();
}
```

should be:

```
if (i==1) {
    player = playGame(computer, human, deck);
    testmethod();
}
```

(obviously `player`, `computer`, `human`, `deck` will need to have been previously defined/initialised)

Comment: see edit* cheers though i shouldve fixed that up before asking. And after fixing them up xcode is telling me there is an expected expression missing from that line :\

Comment: OK - you still need to fix `playGame` and `testMethod` - these are still just function *declarations*, not function *calls* - see edit above.

Comment: if i change it to player = playGame(computer, human, deck) it tells me im missing an expected identifier or (.

Comment: Note the last sentence in the answer above: you need to declare (and perhaps initialise) the variables that your are passing as parameters to `playGame`, and also the variable that will hold the function result (`player`). Without seeing the latest version of your code (and the missing functions) it's hard to give more specific help, but you should have enough information to fix this now.

Comment: ok i think ive found the problem. they all had been declared and initialised in the main method before i called the menu method, i moved those declarations to inside the menu method and now its all good i think. thanks for the help.

Comment: scratch that. the errors just didnt show up until i tried to run it -.- now back to the expected identifier issue
edit: i cahnged it to playGame(&computer, &human, deck); and it seems to be working